# Usefull way of reverting Homogeneous coordinates back to 2d?

Tags: numpy, coordinates, projection

Is there some numpy sugar for reverting Homogeneous coordinates back to 2d coordinates.

So this:

```
[[4,8,2],
6,3,2]]
```

becomes this:

```
[[2,4],
[3,1.5]]
```

Comment: What are `Homogeneous coordinates`? Is there a *non-sugary* way to implement it?

Comment: I can put it different. I want to divide the first two elements of the array by the last element. And the output also should be 2 elements and 3 elements as the example :)

Comment: @Divakar ... triple (xZ, yZ, Z) is called a set of homogeneous coordinates (Wikipedia).. Z is the scalar which should be the same for all points meaning divide by the scalar and slice out the extra dimension ( (a/2)[:,:2] if the above is an array... int it if needed)

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 4):

If you have your input as a vector called `x` you could do

```
x[:-1]/x[-1]
```

---

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([6,3,2])
x[:-1]/x[-1]    # array([ 3. ,  1.5])
```

You can also apply it to multiple coordinates in an array:

```
xs = np.array([[4,8,2],[6,3,2]])
np.array([x[:-1]/x[-1] for x in xs])    # array([[ 2. ,  4. ],
                                        #        [ 3. ,  1.5]])
```

If you want to reuse this you can define a function `homogen`:

```
homogen = lambda x: x[:-1]/x[-1]

# previous stuff becomes something like
np.array([homogen(x) for x in xs])
```

Comment: thats only for one coordinate in an array

Comment: Edited it to include an example for multiple coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

One approach making use of [`broadcasted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) elementwise divisions -

```
from __future__ import division

a[:,:2]/a[:,[-1]]
```

We can use `a[:,-1,None]` or `a[:,-1][:,None]` or `a[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)` in place of `a[:,[-1]]`. With `a[:,[-1]]`, we are keeping the number of dims intact, letting us perform the broadcasting divisions.

Another with [`np.true_divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html) again using `broadcasting` -

```
np.true_divide(a[:,:2], a[:,[-1]])
```

Sample run -

```
In [194]: a
Out[194]: 
array([[4, 8, 2],
       [6, 3, 2]])

In [195]: a[:,:2]/a[:,[-1]]
Out[195]: 
array([[ 2. ,  4. ],
       [ 3. ,  1.5]])

In [196]: np.true_divide(a[:,:2], a[:,[-1]])
Out[196]: 
array([[ 2. ,  4. ],
       [ 3. ,  1.5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy handles broadcasting internally, so you can use the following to avoid for loops:

```
x/x[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.hstack((np.random.randint(0,10,(3,2)), np.ones((3,1))*10))
>>> x
array([[ 1.,  8., 10.],
   [ 7.,  9., 10.],
   [ 1.,  9., 10.]])

>>> x/x[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)
array([[0.1, 0.8, 1. ],
   [0.7, 0.9, 1. ],
   [0.1, 0.9, 1. ]])
```